# android emulator display fails

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, emulation

Is there a version of zone.js that includes checking and handling this issue that I can use short of trying  to edit the files myself. Getting the error when running project app for android. No problem when I run for the web using ng serve only when I try tns run android. I run tns build android fine, so it only fails when attempting to run the generated <.apk> on the android emulator. I am Woring on windows 8. The error is zone already loaded.

Comment: Did you try to run the generated apk on a real device?

Comment: Yes I copied the the apk and installed it on an android device but got the same error on the device when I ran it.